# Which encoding replaces "í" with "\303 \255"?

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding, data-conversion

Anyone knows which encoding is this one. They tell me this is UTF8 but I can't see how.
This input:

> aquí (notice the accent on the i)

shoud produce this:

> aqu\303 \255

Seems this is based on this table https://www.acc.umu.se/~saasha/charsets/, but I can see how I can get the output suggested from a random user input string from .NET - of course without building this crazy conversion table.

Any ideas?

Comment: The string is incorrect, there shouldn't be a space between \303 and \255. Try it for yourself: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is UTF8, and 303 255 *octal* is 195 173 decimal, these numbers probably look more familiar. See the `dec` and `oct` headers in the table you linked.

There is no built-in type that's going to produce octal output for *some* characters - you'll have to decide which characters to "octal-escape" and which to keep.

The following snippet produces the output you desired (without the extra space), and escapes data based on whether a character is within the ASCII set:

```
string str = "aquí";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.Substring(i, 1));
    if (bytes.Length == 1 && bytes[0] < 128)
    {
        output.Append(str[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
        {
            output.Append(@"\" + Convert.ToString(b, 8));
        }
    }
}

string result = output.ToString();
```