# Which encoding replaces "\303 \255" with "í" in java?

Tags: java, encoding

im using java 11. i have this string "\303\255" which get from an api call response.

seems that somehow, the api send it converted.  i want to convert it to charcter "í". in java.

i found similar issues with opposite problems. as you see here

[Which encoding replaces "í" with "\303 \255"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795562/which-encoding-replaces-%c3%ad-with-303-255/74033323?noredirect=1#comment130718212_74033323) ?

Comment: "i have this string "\303\255"" - how are you observing that string? It's not clear whether you've got a string that actually contains backslashes. Is \303\255 what you see if you print it to the console, for example?

Comment: assuming the string really has that content, that is, the characters `'\303'` and `' \255'` (octal values) then: `new String(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`  (but, if the data is being received as bytes, better do the conversion to string already using the correct charset)

Comment: Jon Skeet, thanks. the text indeed contain backSlashees.i saw that in console.  (these are octal values) as user 16320675 said. (below answer)

Comment: thanks user16320675 . now, i know that these are octal. that data recieved as string (not as byte[]). but i didnt understand your answer, what you suggest ? using this command ?         new String(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Comment: i used this >.   String result = new String(value1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);   but still get same situation. the text not converted and it still include \303\255.

Comment: What do you expect - **ÝÅ** ?

Comment: It could actually be Java that did this, these are legal octal escape sequences you can use in source code. If I run `System.out.println("Libert\303\251 Greek Yogourt");` (linux utf8 source) I get `Liberté Greek Yogourt`. When doing that with this code https://udojava.com/tag/string-decode/ I can also reverse the encoding if it appears with literal \ characters. Weirdly enough when using https://ideone.com/cC72cd as an example it prints `LibertÃ© Greek Yogourt`.

Comment: It could be Unicode combining diacritics, in which case, those are not octal values but hex ones. But those particular ones are not 'correct'.

Comment: It is still not clear to me whether your string has the eight characters \, 3, 0, 3, \, 2, 5, 5, or if you are simply seeing an octal *representation* of two bytes in an internal byte array in your String.  Please tell us exactly what steps you are taking to observe the contents of the String.  Don’t just say you saw it on the console;  tell us exactly what you did to make it appear on the console.

Comment: *Never* “fix” a String that way—you will corrupt the data.  The correct way to address this is to fix the code that converts bytes to a String in the first place, and make sure it uses the correct charset.

Answer (score -1):

But the answer to your question *Which encoding replaces "í" with "\303 \255"?*  is - none (probably). Of the well over 1000 character encodings known to `iconv`, none encodes that two-byte sequence to that single character, which is LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE

Comment: indeed, i got many values and the above (was an example) . real example that "LibertÈ Greek Yogourt" appear as "Libert\303\251 Greek Yogourt ". note that the E was converted. i believe \303 is for the char and \251 is for signal (') above it. i dont understand why there is no way to convert\encode these numbers with back slashes to real char  È ? i expect to see the charcter È. thanks

Comment: `echo -e '\u0251\u0301'` gives
ɑ́  Those would be hexadecimal sequences not octal ones, forming what are called 'combining 'diacritics'.

Comment: not sure about `iconv`, but `new String("\303\255".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` results in `"í"` [jshell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VnGW.png) or [IDEone](https://ideone.com/Afxs0j)  || LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE, code point `U+000ED` is `0xC3AD` in UTF-8 (Hex) which is `0303` `0255` (Octal bytes) (from https://decodeunicode.org/en/u+000ED)

Comment: @user16320675 You're dead right. So sorry to all. I had a bad invocation of ```bc``` If you get the input base and output base the wrong way around you can get wrong and nastily misleading results :) My octal conversions to hex were wrong. If you'd like to put up your answer, I'll delete my wrong one